# Change value of boolean flag before parsing

Tags: go, flags

**`sandbox/tmp/main.go`**

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "sandbox/tmp/pac"
)

func main() {
    flag.Set("str_flag", "new_val")
    // flag.Set("bool_flag", true)     // How to set this?
    flag.Parse()
    pac.PrintFlags()
}
```

**`sandbox/tmp/pac/pac.go`**

```
package pac

import "flag"

var (
    boolFlag = flag.Bool("bool_flag", false, "")
    strFlag  = flag.String("str_flag", "def_val", "")
)

func PrintFlags() {
    println(*boolFlag)
    println(*strFlag)
}
```

What's a complement for `flag.Set()` for boolean flags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the string representation that you would provide in the command line, e.g `"true"`:

```
flag.Set("bool_flag", "true")
```

Quoting from [Package doc: Command line flag syntax:](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#hdr-Command_line_flag_syntax)

> Boolean flags may be:
>
> ```
> 1, 0, t, f, T, F, true, false, TRUE, FALSE, True, False
> ```

So the following also work:

```
flag.Set("bool_flag", "1")
flag.Set("bool_flag", "t")
flag.Set("bool_flag", "T")
flag.Set("bool_flag", "TRUE")
flag.Set("bool_flag", "True")
```